# How do I aggregate values in a python list or dictionary based on book title?

Tags: django, list, dictionary

Currently, my data is like this or a dictionary, not aggregated by title:

```
{Great Expectations, Bookstore 1, $8.99},
{Great Expectations, Bookstore 2, $12.99},
{Great Expectations, Bookstore 3, $6.99},
{Tales from the Crypt, Bookstore 1, $5.99},
{The Sisterhood of the Traveling Pants, Bookstore 3, $8.99}
{Oprah: The Icon, Bookstore 2, $6.99}
{Oprah: The Icon, Bookstore 3, $9.99}
```

I'd like to create list of a dictionary of prices that's aggregated by title that looks like this:

```
[Great Expectations, {price1: $6.99, price2: $8.99, price3: $12.99}],
[Tales from the Crypt, {price1: $5.99}],
[The Sisterhood of the.., {price1: $6.99}],
[Oprah: The Icon, {price1: $6.99, price2: $9.99}]
```

Thanks for your help. I will eventually pass this data into a Django view as a list. There can be more than 3 prices, n prices. I'd also like to order the prices from smallest to largest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your initial list of books will follow a standard pattern of the first element being the title, second the bookstore and third price, you could do something like this:

```
aggregrated_books = {}

for book in book_list:
    if aggregrated_books[book[0]]:
        aggregrated_books[book[0]].append(book[2])
    else:
        aggregrated_books[book[0]] = [book[2]]
```

This will output something like:

```
{'Great Expectations': [6.99, 8.99, 12.99],
'Tales from the Crypt': [5.99],
'The Sisterhood of the', [6.99],
'Oprah: The Icon', [6.99, 9.99]}
```

Depending on what your use case for this data is you'd be better off aggregating to a list of prices rather than a dictionary like you included in your question. You can easily add `price1` `price2` etc when iterating through the list later.